# Audio Amplifier Repair Explanation

Tags: transistors, amplifier, audio, repair

I've been trying to repair a Saunsui A-40 amplifier for a long time now, (when it was turned on, magic smoke started to flow).

I found most of the driver and power transistors all shorted, so i replaced them (had to use similar transistors because i couldn't find the originals)

I replaced every transistor in that schematic EXCEPT TR06, that one was not burned)

I checked every datasheet and the transistors i chose are suited for the job. (If it's necessary, i'll show the replacements i used).

The amplifier now turns on fine, but it has almost no output, and its completely distorted, only with volume below 3 you can hear really low an almost not distorted signal. I can't figure out whats causing the problem, every transistor seems OK.

I'll show next both channels schematic. (the full schematic is everywhere on the web)

Right Channel
[image: Measurements Tips]
Left Channel
[image: Component Values]
Transistors
[image: transistors]

All electrolytic capacitors where replaced, and i made sure all resistors are not open circuit.

Voltages measure almost like the indication in the schematic (instead of +/-35V, i have +/-40V, because in my appartment i have 230Vac mains most of the time, all measurments are proportional to the ones in the schematic)

**UPDATE:**

**Test conditions:** 1kHz 1VPP sinewave to the input.

**Voltage Across R78** = 0mV (this doesn't change with the trimmers)

**Voltage @ TR10 collector** = -2.5

**Voltage Across C44** = 2V (meaning the Voltage @ TR12 is -0.5V when it should be 2.5V, is this correct?)

(i've tested with changing the trimmer to -1.2V @ TR10 collector, the TR12 collector is the same -0.5V)

Here is a screenshot of the osciloscope measuring

Channel 1 (yellow): Input

Channel 2 (blue): Collector of TR10 at a volume of 2 (almost OFF)

[image: at 2]

Here is a screenshot of the osciloscope measuring

Channel 1 (yellow): Input

Channel 2 (blue): Collector of TR10 at a volume of 5 (half way)
(maxed to 10 its very similar to this one but of course, sharper square)
[image: at 5]

So, first:

1- Can i solve the voltage @ TR12 collector problem by changing R58 and R69, or this could cause other problems? I doubt those resistors are causing the problem, what is?

2- Does the above problem have anything to do with the saturation of the signal right after TR10? ¿How can i solve that problem? (Note that this continues no matter what i do with the trim pot)

Comment: You should isolate the actual amplification stage and do some calculations, likely the biasing should be rather different for the transistors you used

Comment: Have you changed TR06 as well (long tailed pair) or did you leave that in circuit?

Comment: @JImDearden I'll edit and add that to the post. NO, thats the only transistor i didn't change because its working (or seems to be) fine. Besides it's very likely i won't find a direct replacement, and probably have to use two A1015 (loosing the nice heat and hfe compensation the 2sa798 has)

Comment: You still can find the 2SA798 on Ebay.

Comment: @Decapod You see, i'm from Argentina, so can't buy on Ebay, it's really hard to find specific components here. I was lucky to have found some replacement for the other transistors.

Comment: Are both left & right channels similarly distorted? If one channel is OK, compare with the other non-working channel, with "mono" rather than stereo front-panel selection. A very careful visual inspection of all circuit-board connections is useful when magic smoke happens.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would start by making sure the thing is biased correctly.  Look at the voltage at both bases of the differential pair.  They should both be zero.  If that is the case, then I'd look for the signal on R44.  You should see a nice amplified SIN there.  Next I would check for the points that say 1.2V.  The bottom one on TR16 should be -1.2 not 1.2.  It's hard to say more without component values.  what is the value of R44?

Check to  make sure substitute transistors have the same pin outs as the originals.

Comment: R44 is 6.8k look at the other channel.

Comment: @owg60 Thank you, i'll take a look at that when i get home in a few hours. YES the base of TR16 is -1.2v, should have noted that. Oh, and the values of the components are on the Right Channel schematic, R44 is 6.8k.

Comment: You may know this but TR12 is part of a circuit called a VBE multiplier.  If you don't know, google it.  It's job is to create a voltage source that just keeps all those emitter followers around 0A when the input is zero.  The variable resistor VR02 adjusts this.  When you changed the transistors you would have been extremely lucky if you didn't have to adjust this.  if this is not done properly you will get distortion.

Comment: Just as a side note to those running off to look at VBE multipliers now, TR12 is a VBE multiplier that _isn't_ compensated for the Early effect.

Comment: @owg60 i did start "playing" with the trimmpot, and at no position did the distortion disappeared, nor the 4mV at the output resistors appeared. Is it possible i would have to change the trimmer to a larger value and try then?

Comment: I think it is too soon to say change the value of the trim pot.  If it is not doing it's job, I think you would have distortion at all level, even low levels.  Here is a video that may help you to use your scope to see if the pot is doing its job; https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Obh_PIC2qqo This pot corrects something called crossover distortion.  It is caused by the upper and lower transistors both being off arround 0V.

Comment: @ndelucca , for now, adjust the trimpot for maximum resistance - this is the "safe" end (minimum resistance can cause very much current to flow through output transistors). As long as DC voltage measured from base of TR14 to base of TR16 is less than 2.4v, you should be safe. Look elsewhere.

Comment: @owg60 i made some tests and updated the post

Comment: I'm not sure what I seeing because both scope plots photos are labeled the same.  If the first one is the input and output it is a big help.  The top half of the class b output seems to be working.  what are the base voltages of TR16 and TR20?

Comment: I've studied this a little more.  Your problem is definitely TR16 or TR20.  What is happening is because the signal doesn't reach the output on the negative half of the signal, feedback is gone.  No feedback means the very large gain of the TR10 stage, which is working. goes very negative quickly.  Make sure your substitute transistors don't have a different pin out.  If you see the same wave at the same signal at TR20 base as TR10 collector then TR16 is good and the problem is TR20.

Comment: @owg60 Both osciloscope pictures are of the same test points. The channel 1 (yellow) is the input. Channel 2 (blue) is the collector of TR10 (and its the same as the base for TR14 and TR16). The actual output of the amplifier is a minute square wave of a few hundred mV. Do think that TR16 or TR20 are the cause? I could have sworn it should have to be TR10 or surroundings.

Comment: (only difference in both situations is the volume control, the first one is set to 2, and the second one is set to 5). i corrected the post

Comment: If TR14 and TR16 are working, you should see a replica of this signal at their emitters.  Is that what you get?

Comment: @owg60 "every transistor seems OK" what the hell was i thinking.... Indeed both replacements i used for TR15 and 16 where reversed.... i guess i must have seen the datasheet wrong the first attempt, so basically i've been punching the head against the wall for a week because of my own comfort zone of not doubting myself..... Thank you you've made my day. If youll edit the Answer to this i'll mark it as Solved. Thanks again.

Comment: @owg60 I guess i'll start getting ready for the walk of shame..

Comment: By elimination the transistor I called TR14 must really be TR15. It is a little obscured by the red circle. I'd like to see If I can under stand your scope photos better.  Can you tell me how the pins were substituted? Was it C and E reversed?  Have you replaced the parts and now it is working?

Comment: @owg60 TR16 (and TR15 on the other channel) was backwards, C in place of E and E in place of C, i turned it around and both transistors are working now. I have another problem now that it's distorting the signal quite a bit, but i'll start checking that tomorrow. I'll probably have to start by fine adjusting the bias and check the rest of the circuit.

Comment: Sadly when the transistors were in backwards, their emitter base junctions probably when into breakdown.  The bad thing about this is it can cause Bf degradation.  The datasheets probably gives this breakdown voltage as 5 or 6 Volts.  This may be the cause of distortion now.